# Catch exception and throw different exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I found this in our code. I am trying to find some scenario, where this could make sense. But so far I didn't find any reason to catch exception then throw new and catch also that one. Can you please clarify this or potentially suggest some similar topic? I didn't find anything by myself.

```
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle SQL exception
    e.printStackTrace();
    log.error("SQLException occured in getSeverityList(), errMsg : " + e.getMessage());
    try {
        throw new Exception("Error In getSeverityList(): " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
} finally {
```

I tried already to look for scenario, where something like this makes sense, but without success.

Comment: This way of handling exception doesn't make much sense, no, for multiple reasons... I would either get rid of the entire `catch` (so `SQLException` is thrown up), wrap the exception in a **more specific** business exception, or I would remove the first `e.printStackTrace()`, and amend the logging to `log.error("SQLException occured in getSeverityList()", e)` (assuming a logging API is used which logs exception stracktraces when offered an exception like this), and get rid of the entire nested try-catch.

Comment: There is literally no point in doing this. You don't need to throw an exception to catch it to print its stack trace: `new Exception(...).printStackTrace();` does the same. But then, you've already got that stack trace, plus extra information, from `e.printStackTrace()`; so there's no point in doing that either.